# Rails: where condition with "OR is NULL" inside

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to get all the records where a datetime attribute is either NULL or within a timeframe. How can I add a  `or where disbursed_at IS NULL` to the condition inside the `where`?
My actual query is way longer, I wouldn't want to repeat it all using `.or`

```
Investor.left_join(:disbursements).where(disbursements: { disbursed_at: year_period })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking you can add an `OR column_X IS NULL` condition by providing an `Array`, containing at least one `nil` element, as part of the `Hash` arguments.

For Example:

```
Investor
  .left_join(:disbursements)
  .where(disbursements: { disbursed_at: [year_period,nil] })
```

Assuming `year_period` is a `Range` this should result in

```
SELECT 
  investors.* 
FROM 
  investors 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN disbursements ON disbursements.investor_id = investors.id
WHERE 
  disbursements.disbursed_at BETWEEN xxxxx AND xxxxx 
  OR disbursements.disbursed_at IS NULL
```